# Error: Invalid tsconfig - src/tsconfig.app.json

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-universal

I was trying to install Angular Universal to an existing project, so I ran the following commands:

```
npm i @nguniversal/express-engine
ng generate universal --client-project website
```

But after running the second line I get the below error:

```
Invalid tsconfig - src/tsconfig.app.json
```

I don't really know why this error is persisting, I've looked at the tsconfig.app.json file and everything looks fine. Below are the files:

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "files": [
    "atc-main.ts",
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "typings.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "esnext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": ["../node_modules/@types"],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["./app/*"],
      "@account/*": ["./account/*"],
      "@shared/*": ["./shared/*"],
      "@node_modules/*": ["../node_modules/*"],
      "@angular/*": ["../node_modules/@angular/*"],
      "@metronic/*": ["./assets/metronic/*"]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "strictInputTypes": false,
    "strictAttributeTypes": false,
    "strictOutputEventTypes": false,
    "strictDomEventTypes": false,
    "strictLiteralTypes": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this an ionic app?

Comment: No, it is a normal angular project

Comment: Try using the command `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine` instead, installation template might do more things under the hood than just installing a package.

Comment: I get the same error when running the above command

Comment: Edit `tsconfig.json` break down single line brakcets [] to multiline e.g `"typeRoots": [<newline>"../node_modules/@types"<newline>],` just like you have `tsconfig.app.json`.

Comment: How will adding new lines solve the issue? I tried it nonetheless and unfortunately, still the same error.

Comment: Include `"compilerOptions": {"outDir": "./out-tsc/app", "types": ["node"]}` in tsconfig

Comment: Still no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `tsconfig.app.json` was missing `compilerOptions`.
2. Check `src/` reference in `files`. Same for `"atc-main.ts"`, is the location reference okay? Does `"typings.d.ts"` exist?
3. Validate all lines, s.t. they point to something that exists.

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/atc-main.ts"
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "typings.d.ts"
  ]
}
```